# The issue in RouteCollection.php in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

Could you please assist me in resolving the following error in Laravel 4?

```
[2015-03-01 23:54:17] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1054): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1022): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\blog\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Share some code here!

Comment: JAZAkallah Arslan bro i am hitting wrong route. silly mistake, some time laughing when caught mistake in programming like that

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a url for which no route is defined.

Either define the route or change the url you're requesting.